# runtime error 5854 string parameter is too long

Tags: vba

I use following macro and sometimes it gives parameter is too long error. how can I solve it?

```
Sub BoldFirstLetterInSentence()
Dim s As Range
Dim doc1 As Document
Dim doc2 As Document

Set doc1 = Word.Documents("Doc1.docx")
Set doc2 = Word.Documents("Doc2.docx")

For Each s In doc1.Sentences
    If s.Characters(1).Bold = True Then
        Debug.Print s
        With doc2
            Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
            With Selection.Find
                .Text = s
                .Replacement.Text = ""
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Format = False
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False
                .MatchWildcards = False
                .MatchSoundsLike = False
                .MatchAllWordForms = False
            End With
            a = Selection.Find.Execute
            If a = True Then
                Selection.Font.Bold = True
            End If
        End With
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 9):

I figured out an answer to this - hopefully it's of some use 3 years on.

In my application, I'm replacing all occurrences of the string "{Text}" in a document with the replacement text.

The approach is to break the replacement text into "chunks" of 250 characters, and if there are any more chunks remaining, append a new replacement variable ({1} for the first chunk, {2} for the second, etc.), then repeat.

My code below runs in Word 2010 VBA:

```
Private Sub SearchAndReplace(search As String, replace As String)

Dim i As Integer
Dim chunks As Integer
Dim chunk As String

Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToSection, Which:=wdGoToFirst ' Go to the start of the document

With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .MatchCase = True
    .MatchWholeWord = True

    ' We get error 5854 if the replacement text is greater than 255 characters, so need to work around
    ' How many 250 character "chunks" are there in the replacement text?
    chunks = Round(Len(replace) / 250, 0)                   ' Use 250 to allow for {1}, etc.
    If Len(replace) Mod 250 > 0 Then chunks = chunks + 1      ' Workaround because there's no Ceiling()

    If chunks = 1 Then
        .Execute FindText:="{" & search & "}", ReplaceWith:=replace, replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Else

        ' Replace existing replacement variable (e.g. {Text}) the first chunk's replacement variable (i.e. {1})
        .Execute FindText:="{" & search & "}", ReplaceWith:="{1}", replace:=wdReplaceAll

        ' Replace the text in chunks of less than 255 characters
        For i = 1 To chunks

            ' Get the
            chunk = Mid(replace, ((i - 1) * 250) + 1, 250)

            ' Add the replacement variable for the next chunk to the end of the string
            If i < chunks Then chunk = chunk & "{" & (i + 1) & "}"

            .Execute FindText:="{" & i & "}", ReplaceWith:=chunk, replace:=wdReplaceAll
        Next i

    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I just used this. So thx. I found a small issue if you replace with an empty string, you replace with "{1}" instead. This can be easily fixed though by replacing the "If chunks = 1 then" with "If chunks <= 1 then".

Comment: Thanks! Useful 10 years on!. Don't forget to add `const wdReplaceAll=2`

Comment: And also not sure why the curly brackets are necessary in `Execute FindText:="{" & search & "}"`. When I removed them then the code worked

Answer (score 5):

The answer is much simpler than those given here.  Don't use Replacement.  Simply select the text you want to replace, then TYPE over it.

```
With ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection
    .WholeStory
    .Find.ClearFormatting
    .Find.Execute FindText:="Whatever you want to replace"
    Options.ReplaceSelection = True
    .TypeText Text:="Type away to your heart's content.  This string can be as long as it needs to be.  What you're doing here is selecting the part you want to replace, then just start typing, same as you would if you were using Word for real.  Because Selection selects the word you want to replace, when you start typing, that will be replaced with the new text as you type.  No need to worry about String length limitations."
End With
```

Comment: This doesn't even compile (VB.NET in VS 2017), but it's on the right track and can be made to work.

Comment: I was able to use the same code but without this line: .WholeStory

Comment: works fine, just merge into your context.

Answer (score 2):

```
' in the archive word, you have put [1], in the place that want to made the change
Dim dirr As String
dirr = ThisWorkbook.Path ' this content url or path of actual archive
Dim objSelection
Dim objWord As Object
If objWord Is Nothing Then
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(dirr & "\a1.dotx") & "TEMPLEATE WORD" ' this content archive WORD or TEMPLEATE.
objWord.Visible = True
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

' Changes in the "WORD"
Dim cant As Integer
Dim tex As String
Dim max As Integer
Dim total As Integer
Dim final As Integer
final = 1
cant = 1
max = 200 ' this is amount of character that it go have divide, then Visual Basic only allows 250. In this case is 200

'Sheets("Programas").Cells(1, 1).Value. This have the string > 250 Caracters, but it divides in cant = 200.
total = Len(Sheets("Programas").Cells(1, 1).Value) ' this have total characters of the string.

Do While total > (cant) * max
    ' this "while" divides string in "cant = 200", example 1200 Characters, this "while" divides the string in 6 parts.
    With objWord.Selection.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .MatchCase = True
            .MatchWholeWord = True
            .Text = "[1]" ' shearch [1] and replace by "cant = 200"
            tex = Mid(Sheets("Programas").Cells(1, 1).Value, final, max) ' this content "cant = 200" characters, actual
            .Replacement.Text = tex & "[1]" ' this replace "cant = 200" and finally to add [1],for the next "cant = 200" Characters
            cant = cant + 1
            final = max * (cant - 1) ' this have the character actual for to divide in "cant = 200", example ---> 0 position ..... "190 Characteres" other 10 Characters ------ THIS IS FINAL = 200 -------- 201 Character -----> NEXT "cant = 200"
            .Execute Replace:=2
    End With
Loop


'This made the same that prev Procces, in the last "cant = 200"

With objWord.Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .Text = "[1]"
        tex = Mid(Sheets("Programas").Cells(1, 1).Value, final, total)
        .Replacement.Text = tex
        .Execute Replace:=2
End With
```

Comment: Hi! I think it would be a great idea if you could add some short text to describe your code sample. So that less experienced users can understand your answer with more ease.

Comment: i have made the changes in the comments, i hope to be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks, that looks much better :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the maximum length of a replace string in this context is 255 characters.  I am guessing that sometimes your sentence length is more than that, which is causing the error.  Your best bet is to use smaller chunks of strings for replacement.

Comment: it is beyond my power. there are some documents and I can't change it.

Comment: Since you have no control over the documents, you either need to change your approach (i.e. not do it at the sentence level) or find a way to do it with your full sentences.  One option I saw on another forum was to place your source text on the clipboard and change your replacement text to "^c".  Another option would be to use a third party library that does not impose the 255 character limitation.

Comment: @JohnKoerner Thank you for mentioning the ^c workaround - it saved me a great deal of time and was very simple to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone is looking for something similar in C#:

```
private static void ReplaceText(Find find, string findText, string replaceText) {
        find.ClearFormatting();
        find.Text = findText;
        find.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
        find.Replacement.Text = replaceText;
        object replaceAll = WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
        find.Execute(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref replaceAll, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
    }

private static void ReplaceTextInRange(Range range, Dictionary<string, string> replacements) {
        var find = range.Find;

        foreach (var replacement in replacements) {
            int maxLen = 255;
            if (replacement.Value.Length > maxLen) {
                //For longer text, we need to break it up. We use a special delimiter at the end of each chunk to mark the position for the next replacement operation.
                const string specialDelim = "{={=}=}";
                ReplaceText(find, replacement.Key, specialDelim);
                var chunkSize = maxLen - specialDelim.Length;
                SplitIntoChunks(replacement.Value, chunkSize, (chunk, i, isLast) =>
                    ReplaceText(find, specialDelim, chunk + (isLast ? "" : specialDelim))
                    );

            } else {
                ReplaceText(find, replacement.Key, replacement.Value);
            }
        }
    }

private static void SplitIntoChunks(string value, int size, Action<string, int, bool> fn) {
        var cnt = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)value.Length / size);
        if (cnt <= 1) {
            fn(value, 0, true);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
            string chunk = value.Substring(i * size, Math.Min(size, value.Length - i * size));
            fn(chunk, i, i == cnt - 1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone need to handle limit of the word length of the search text.
Below is the code to do it:

```
Private Function SearchAndReplaceText(ByVal StrSearch As String, ByVal StrReplace As String) As Boolean

Dim i As Integer
Dim divisions As Integer
Dim chunk As String

Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToSection, Which:=wdGoToFirst ' Go to the start of the document

With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .MatchCase = True
    .MatchWholeWord = True

    ' We get error 5854 if the text property of selection is greater than 255 characters, so need to work around
    ' How many 250 character "divisions" are there in the search text?
    divisions = Round(Len(StrSearch) / 250, 0) 
    If Len(StrSearch) Mod 250 > 0 Then divisions = divisions + 1 

    If divisions = 1 Then
        .Execute Findtext:=StrSearch, ReplaceWith:=StrReplace, Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue
        SearchAndReplaceText = True
    Else
        ' Replace the text in divisions of less than 255 characters
        For i = 1 To divisions

            ' Get the text chunk by chunk
            chunk = Mid(StrSearch, ((i - 1) * 250) + 1, 250)

            .Execute Findtext:=chunk, ReplaceWith:=StrReplace, Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue
        Next i
        SearchAndReplaceText = True
    End If
End With

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a possible solution.

```
Selection.Find.Execute FindText:="MonTexte"
Selection.Range.Text = "abcefg abcefg abcefg abcefg abcefg abcefg abcefg abcefg abcefg abcefg abcefg abcefg abcefg abcefg abcefg abcefg abcefg abcefg abcefg abcefg abcefg abcefg abcefg abcefg abcefg abcefg abcefg abcefg abcefg abcefg abcefg abcefg abcefg abcefg abcefg abcefg abcefg abcefg abcefg abcefg"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).