# Method Replace, execution error 13 when strings are big

Tags: ms-access, vba

In a old script, I use the method Replace for translate the excel sheets to an another language. 
But now, I would replace some string but sometimes I get an execution error 13 "Type mismatch".

I noticed when the String is big (length >~ 400 characters), the method replace return this error.

By example, here I haven't problem :

```
Sheets(sheet).Cells.Replace "toto", "tata", xlWhole
```

But here :

```
Sheets(sheet).Cells.Replace "WWWWWWWWWWWW", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", xlWhole
```

I get the error "Type mismatch (Error 13)"
I tried to force the type of the data

```
var temp as string
temp = "AAAAAAAA...."
```

But it doesn't work...
Can I fix it ? Are there another solution ?

Thanks =)

Comment: I didn't see this post ! Thanks you Veve =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20883352/4074148) :  dividing the string into smaller chunks of 250 chars and then treat them as "normal" string seems to do the trick.