# Excel VBA Macro - Replace a Reference word on Microsoft Word with a sentence above 255 from Excel

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

I want to replace a Reference word [Property Manager Notes] on Word with a paragraph which is greater than 255 words from Excel. There will be more references like these.

Could anyone help please.

Here is the picture to get an idea:

[image: [picture]

Here is the code I'm using

```
 Dim objWord
   Dim objDoc
   Dim oCell  As Integer
  Sub Replacing_excel_word()

 Sheets("Work").Select

   Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\Users\Sai\Desktop\xyz.docx")

objWord.Visible = True

objWord.Activate

For oCell = 1 To 50

from_text = Sheets("Work").Range("A" & oCell).Value
to_text = Sheets("Work").Range("B" & oCell).Value

With objWord.ActiveDocument
    Set myRange = .Content
    With myRange.Find
        .Execute FindText:=from_text, ReplaceWith:=to_text, Replace:=1
    End With
End With

Next oCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Does the code throw an error? Does it not run properly? Does it not replace with what you expect? Does it ....what does it do or not do?

Comment: VBA - runtime error "String parameter too long."

Comment: [This may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050902/runtime-error-5854-string-parameter-is-too-long)

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem. At the end of your code you need to create a function:

```
Function Replacement255(wRng, field, content)


        With wRng.Find
            .text = field   '>> enter the text to be searched and replaced
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False

          If Len(content) > 255 Then
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
              cnt = 0
              Do
                 strFragment1 = Mid(content, cnt + 1, 230)
                 cnt = cnt + 230
                 If Len(strFragment1) > 0 Then strFragment1 = strFragment1 & "@@@@@@@@@@"
                 .Replacement.text = strFragment1
                 .Execute , , , , , , , , , , wdReplaceOne
                 .text = "@@@@@@@@@@"
              Loop While Len(strFragment1) > 0
          Else
            .Replacement.text = text  '>> enter column location of the text from excel
                .Wrap = wdFindStop
              .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
          End If

          End With

End Function
```

And then, in your code, you need to use this function:

```
 Replacement255 wRng, field, content.Value
```

where:

field: text to replace ex. "#Enter here#"
content: text to replace with ex. `Sheet1.Cells(MyRow, "M")`

I hope it helps you!