# Error 5854 - string parameter is too long?

Tags: vba

This code used to work fine in word-VBA, but now it gives a runtime error 5854 (string parameter too long). How can I fix it? Please help!

```
    Dim rngTemp As Range

Set rngTemp = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=0, End:=0)

With rngTemp.Find

    .ClearFormatting
    .Highlight = False
    .MatchWholeWord = True

    With .Replacement
        .ClearFormatting
        .Highlight = True
    End With
    
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, FindText:=searchNo, ReplaceWith:=newtext, Format:=True
    
    If .Found = True Then
        totalCount = totalCount + 1
    End If

End With
```

Comment: What is `searchNo` and `newtext`?  There is a limit for the replacement string, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050902/runtime-error-5854-string-parameter-is-too-long

Comment: Does this answer your question? [runtime error 5854 string parameter is too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050902/runtime-error-5854-string-parameter-is-too-long)