# Highlighting words from List

Tags: vba, ms-word

The following code works in word document, but it runs slow - is there any way to speed up the process (like putting it into chunks or something?), I have no experience in coding (over 4000 items in list, 150 pages in main doc).

```
Sub B2_Highlighter_Selection_andAllWordForms()
  Dim FRDoc As Document, FRList() As String, i As Long, aRng As Range
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
    Set FRDoc = Documents.Open("C:\path.docx", ReadOnly:=True, Addtorecentfiles:=False, Visible:=False)
    FRList = Split(FRDoc.Range.Text, vbCr)
    FRDoc.Close False
    'FRList = Split("Document True Text ClearFormatting", " ") 'for testing only
    Set FRDoc = Nothing
    Set aRng = Selection.Range
    With aRng.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .MatchWholeWord = True
      .MatchCase = False
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .Replacement.Text = "^&"
      .Replacement.Highlight = True
      For i = 0 To UBound(FRList)   'Process each word from the List
        If Trim(FRList(i)) <> "" Then
          .Text = Trim(FRList(i))
          .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End If
      Next
    End With
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The macro works in highlighting the text from a list, but is slow.

Comment: You're running Find & Replace 4000 times in a 150 page document, of course it's slow. But it's still doing it faster than you could do it yourself. You could break up the list into several smaller lists, but then it would take longer overall as you would need to run the separate routines for each smaller list.

Comment: That is a reasonable approach, but is it possible to breaking the list into smaller lists through macro. Would the macro run faster if breaking the replacement text into chunks (see Andrew's answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050902/runtime-error-5854-string-parameter-is-too-long). If so, how can this be incorporated into the code?

Comment: The question you linked to addresses the character limit of `Find.Text` and `Find.Replacement.Text`. It has no relevance to your question.